# WebBrowse.Navigate() Crashes Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, task

Sometime Window.navigate hangs my problem.It does not throw any exception.It just freezes my application.Below is the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
           public MainWindow()
           {
              InitializeComponent();
           }

           private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {
             try
             {
                 webBrowse.Navigate(new Uri(@"D:\Resume.docx"));
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {

                MessageBox.Show("Some thing went wrong");
              }
        }
     }
```

I want to implement some kind of timeout in Window.navigate so that if it hangs for more than 5 second i should stop the excution of the Window.Navigate and message pop should pop up.I cannot use task's because i get error for cross threading since it is a wpf.So could any body suggest how to write a function which gets terminated if it takes more than 5 second.

Comment: A .docx file should be opened with Process.Start(), not with a web browser.  You can't reasonably diagnose or fix problems caused by a browser extension.  Only terminating your program with Environment.FailFast() would be a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for answering,but my requirement is that i need to open the doc inside wpf,that's why i used Window.Navigate